# Relocating a ClickOnce deployment

Tags: deployment, clickonce

Has anyone had any experience in relocating a ClickOnce deployment? I have deployed several applications via ClickOnce internal to my company, and now the drive hosting the apps has been moved to a different computer on a different network mapping.

What parts of the "config" do I need to change to reflect the move? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do configure from this inside the VS2008 properties.

```
 1. Go to Project Properties --> Publish --> Updates
 2. Add the new location/server to the Update Location text.
 3. Publish the project one last time to the Original Publish location.
 4. Publish all future updates to the location in step 2.
```